# Keyword not supported: 'server'. Old ASP.NET webforms system

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string

I have an old system using .NET 4.0, ASP.NET, Entity Framework, C# and SQL Server 2014.

I keep getting this error when trying to run the system, it used to work before!

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'server'.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.]
>
> System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms) +10219986
> System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms) +114
> System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +400
> System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString) +56
> Providers.ssirsMembershipProvider.GetFailedPasswordWindowForUser(String username) +111
> _Default.Login2_LoginError(Object sender, EventArgs e) +119
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnLoginError(EventArgs e) +139
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +11591419
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +111
> System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +50
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1890

It has something to do with my connection string in my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" 
         connectionString="server=svrDatabases;database=MyDatabase;uid=myuser;pwd=*****" 
         providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" />
    <add name="myEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=svrDatabases;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tried changing the `providername` to `EntityClient`, doesn't make any difference.

Banging my head against a wall.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Is it case sensitive? i.e. should it be `System.Data.SqlClient` rather than `System.Data.SQLClient` ?

Comment: When was `myConnectionString` added? That's what the error complains about. It looks like it was entered manually, including typos like `System.Data.SQLClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`. The data access library is ADO.NET, not EF, and in *all* .NET versions going back to 2002 the server name is passed using `Data Source`. The second connection string uses that keyword. The *second* connection string uses `Data Source` and `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: It's not a good idea to have two connection strings pointing to the same database. You'll have to keep both of them up to date or risk connecting to different databases or using different credentials. You can avoid typos if you use Visual Studio's built-in connection settings editor.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server connection entry should look like this (when using SQL Server authentication):

```
<add name="CONNECTION_NAME" 
     connectionString="data source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;User Id=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For more options check https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/